# Does exchangeability imply conditional independence?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, conditional-probability

Let $A,B,C$ be a sequence of exchangeable random variables, i.e. $P(A=a,B=b,C=c) = P(B=b,A=a,C=c)=P(C=c,B=b,A=a)$

and so on for any permutation of $\{A=a,B=b,C=c\}$.

Is $P(A=a,B=b|C=c) = P(A=a|C=c)P(B=b|C=c)$?

---

I'm working through a proof that assumes this, but I can't seem to prove this simple result (and even suspect it isn't true).

I know we want to show the following equality
$\frac{P(A=a,B=b,C=c)}{P(C=c)} = \frac{P(A=a,C=c)}{P(C=c)} \times \frac{P(B=b,C=c)}{P(C=c)}$. But I'm not sure how.

Comment: I am not sure what exchangeable is supposed to mean.  Are A, B, C, really random variables?  Or are they events?  If they're rv's, it's not really clear what P(A,B,C) means (though it can be made clear).  If they're events, all events are exchangable.

Comment: Your definition is still off; it should be $P(A=a,B=b,C=c)=P(A=b,B=c,C=a)=\dots$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not true that $A$ and $B$ are conditionally independent given $C$. For example, shuffle a deck of three cards, two of which are black and one of which is red, and let $A$ (resp. $B,C$) equal $1$ when the first (resp. second, third) card is red, and $0$ otherwise. Then $A,B,C$ are exchangeable, but neither two are independent given the third.